# Can't connect my Mac Pro4 to a Wifi

Tags: network, hardware-recommendation

I've always had an Ethernet cable to connect to, until now. There is a wireless Internet signal at my location but I think this computer may not have the hardware to connect? I don't see the antenna icon that would normally appear in the bar at the top on Wifi equipped machines.

**What do I need to purchase for this computer so it can connect to a wifi?**

Answer (score 1):

To see if your Mac Pro4 has a wifi device installed, go to System Preferences > Network and see if Wi-Fi appears in the list of connection types:

[image: Connection types list]

If you *do* have a wifi device installed, you can turn on its menu bar icon by clicking this checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a USB Wireless Adapter [Amazon search](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_8?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb+wireless+adapter&sprefix=usb+wire%2Caps%2C150), [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb+wireless+adapter)

You could also go for a PCI wireless card.

You could also go for the Airport Extreme card.  I believe the model you need is `MB988ZM/A`